# Using a html dropdown list to get the correct display text by value

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have some html that creates a dropdown list. The list has text values and text that is displayed to the user. I save some XML based on the “values” the user selects. At some other point in time I need to parse the XML and display the original text but not in the original list. At this point I only have the “value” from the list and not its display text. At first I was going to use a switch statement to get the display text but then had the idea of using the information that is held in the list. Is it possible to use a bit of javascript to use the value I have to look-up the display version on the list? If so, can someone supply a code snippet? I’ve tried different ways but so far drawn a blank. Shown below is a sample of the html that makes up the list.

```
'<select id="ifmgr_tr_Field">' +
'<option value="DeviceId">Device ID</option>' +
'<option value="DeviceMac">Device MAC</option>' +
'<option value="DeviceType">Device Type</option' +
'</select>';
```

Let’s say I have a value of “DeviceMac”, what I want from this list is “Device MAC”. Remember that I don’t want to use the list to display the value at this point.

EDIT

I could do this but it feels a bit dirty.

```
var item = $('#ifmgr_tr_Field')[0] ;
item.value = field; // field would be the value I have, EG “DeviceMac”
var text = item.options[item.selectedIndex].text; // This will give me “Device MAC” which is what I want.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this might help. Well it still has a if condition. But as you said the value in the ListBox does not change. It uses list as a look-up and finds the option where the Text of option is "Device MAC" for example. emm... well i used jQuery cause it have a better loop(each) function than traditional javascript.

```
    $('#ifmgr_tr_Field option').each(function () {
        var option = this;
        if(option.text == 'Device MAC')
        alert(option.text + " Value : " + option.value);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure EXACTLY what you want to do in the JS function, but  you'll need to add the **onchange** attribute to your select item. It will need to point to your JS function, and pass the value when changed.

```
'<select onchange="doTheFunction(this.value);" id="ifmgr_tr_Field">' + ...
```

Then in your JS Code:

```
function doTheFunction(val){

   //val will hold the newly selcted value

   if (val=="DeviceId"){
      //do something for DeviceId

   } else if (val=="DeviceMac"){
      //do something for DeviceMac

   } else if (val=="DeviceType"){
      //do something for DeviceType

   }
}
```

Comment: I probably didn’t describe the problem very well. I don’t want to have an “if” statement as I wanted the List to provide me with what I want. I have edited my question with a snippet of code that works but changes the list visually as it provides me with the answer I need. Can I do something similar (using the list as a look-up) but without changing the display?